# Взаимодействие WPF и Azure

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, xaml, azure

Всех приветствую. Я пишу программу на WPF. Мне нужно сделать сетевую бд. Изначально мой проект сам создает базу данных, но только в sql server management studio. Я подключил уже к азуру свою бд из sql и теперь надо эту базу данных сделать сетевой. Может подскажет кто нибудь, как подключить азур к проекту впф и как сделать эту базу данных сетевой?

Comment: API-сервер нужен, который будет работать с базой, а WPF клитент - с API сервером. Почти весь интернет так работает. ASP.NET Core Web API например.